# While I was trying to reject a wrong edit it was approved

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I've reached just today the rep for accessing review queues, so I may be missing something. The problem is about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18801999/revisions) and the related edit. From the history it is clear that the first editor made a very minor edit with a fairly big mistake: it changed a reference to "(the Windows) registry" with a generic "a registry", showing he is clueless about the problem at hand. I think he was in good faith, and the true fault is with the reviewers that didn't spot that that single "a" article made the OP question more ambiguous at least. I immediately did a new edit to correct it, but I don't know if there is a better way to tackle such cases (let alone the editor getting +2 rep for a **wrong** edit and almost no effort, since it was too minor anyway).

Comment: The "reviewer" in this case was mainly the OP.

Comment: Wow there, that's not a huge deal, and is probably more of a slight deficiency in the English language than the editor being a complete idiot as you seem to imply. Take it easy, that's a pretty minor error compared to the atrocities you'll get to see regularly in there.

Comment: @Mat I didn't mean the editor was an idiot, but that he really didn't know the content of the post (maybe he knows C, but not Windows and its API). As I said I think he was in good faith, but careless. Sorry if my tone seemed a bit too alarmed :-). I just wanted to know if my behavior in this case was correct, or if I should have done something else (more incisive?). As I said the biggest fault was with the peer reviewers IMHO.

Comment: @Bart I know how to see who are the reviewers of my posts, but how can I discover it for any post? I cannot find the right path in the UI.

Comment: Nothing more needs to be done, the mistake is corrected. (Please don't this sort of thing: "The previous editor was not knowledgeable enough" in edit summaries.) In the edit history, there's a link to the reviews for each edit that was reviewed on the right, just above the editor's name.

Comment: @Mat thanks for the tip! I just wasn't sure how to "flag" the problem. Is there a way to change that edit comment of mine? If a mod or a high rep person could, please do.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: short of asking a dev to hack the database, no. Don't worry too much about it though, essentially no-one reads them (-:

Comment: @Mat Ok! Happy to hear I didn't do more harm than good in the end :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reviewer there was the OP of the question, casting the binding accept vote. In such a case, all you can do is make the edit you've made and leave it at that. Mistakes happen, and we always have the means to correct them. And correcting is all we need to do.